How can I multiply all company values by 'Total General' values while keeping 'Total General' unchanged in a DataFrame?
I have a Pivot table in Python with the following structure.
I want to create a new DataFrame where:
The values of all companies (Amazon, Chedraui, Jüsto, Rappi, Uber) are multiplied by the corresponding values of 'Total General' for each year.
The values of 'Total General' remain unchanged in the resulting DataFrame.
In other words, the new DataFrame should have 'Total General' values identical to the original DataFrame, and all other company values should be scaled by the 'Total General' values.
Here is the current code I am using to generate the pivot:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rich import print
df = pd.read_csv('data_graf_som.csv')

def plot_som_charts(catcp_filter,mesesin):
    
    # Leer el archivo CSV
    df = pd.read_csv('data_graf_som.csv')

    # Filtrar los datos para los años 2023 y 2024, hasta junio
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month.1'])
    df = df[(df['Year'] == 2023) & (df['Date'].dt.month <= mesesin) |
            (df['Year'] == 2024) & (df['Date'].dt.month <= mesesin)]
    df = df[df['CATCP'] == catcp_filter]  

    # Calcular el Year-to-Date (YTD) del SOM para cada año y compañía
    grouped = df.groupby(['Year', 'Company']).agg({
        ' CPUSD': 'sum',
        ' SalesCD': 'sum'
    }).reset_index()

    # Calcular el total general por año
    total_general = grouped.groupby('Year').agg({
        ' CPUSD': 'sum',
        ' SalesCD': 'sum'
    }).reset_index()
    total_general['Company'] = 'Total General'

    # Añadir la fila de total general al DataFrame de datos agrupados
    result = pd.concat([grouped, total_general], ignore_index=True)

    # Ordenar el DataFrame para que las filas de total general aparezcan al final de cada año
    result = result.sort_values(by=['Year', 'Company']).reset_index(drop=True)

    result['SOM'] = result[' CPUSD'] / result[' SalesCD']

    # Pivotar el DataFrame para que los años sean columnas
    pivot_df_year = result.pivot(index='Company', columns='Year', values='SOM')
    return pivot_df_year

df_2=plot_som_charts('TP',6)   

df_2

Just to really clarify the result im looking would look like this
I tried this way:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from rich import print
df = pd.read_csv('data_graf_som.csv')

def plot_som_charts(catcp_filter,mesesin):
    
    # Leer el archivo CSV
    df = pd.read_csv('data_graf_som.csv')

    # Filtrar los datos para los años 2023 y 2024, hasta junio
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month.1'])
    df = df[(df['Year'] == 2023) & (df['Date'].dt.month <= mesesin) |
            (df['Year'] == 2024) & (df['Date'].dt.month <= mesesin)]
    df = df[df['CATCP'] == catcp_filter]  

    # Calcular el Year-to-Date (YTD) del SOM para cada año y compañía
    grouped = df.groupby(['Year', 'Company']).agg({
        ' CPUSD': 'sum',
        ' SalesCD': 'sum'
    }).reset_index()

    # Calcular el total general por año
    total_general = grouped.groupby('Year').agg({
        ' CPUSD': 'sum',
        ' SalesCD': 'sum'
    }).reset_index()
    total_general['Company'] = 'Total General'

    # Añadir la fila de total general al DataFrame de datos agrupados
    result = pd.concat([grouped, total_general], ignore_index=True)

    # Ordenar el DataFrame para que las filas de total general aparezcan al final de cada año
    result = result.sort_values(by=['Year', 'Company']).reset_index(drop=True)

    result['SOM'] = result[' CPUSD'] / result[' SalesCD']

    # Pivotar el DataFrame para que los años sean columnas
    pivot_df_year = result.pivot(index='Company', columns='Year', values='SOM')
    return pivot_df_year

df_2=plot_som_charts('TP',6)   

df_2

df_3 = pd.DataFrame(df_2).set_index('Year')

total_general = df_3.loc['Total General']

for col in df_3.columns:
    if col != 'Total General':
        df_3[col] = df_3[col] * total_general

df_3.loc['Total General'] = total_general

df_3


And got this error: KeyError: "None of ['Year'] are in the columns"
I tried another approach but defining the index as the Company and got a similiar one.
Finally I checked my columns and got this:
*Index([2023, 2024], dtype='int64', name='Year')
*
I guess I cannot see the solution even though I have the years as my index. I would really appreciate some help here :)

My picture is on the code block, but here it is. As you can see I added the pivot I get and the wanted outcome: https://i.sstatic.net/VANl2jth.png

read notice: [mre] & isolate your problem.

It's kind of hard to understand the problem without visualizing the .csv file. But, let me try to help anyway.
Before concat, do this:
grouped=grouped.merge(total_general,on='Year')
grouped['SOM_times_total']=(grouped[' CPUSD_x']/grouped[' SalesCD_x'])*(grouped[' CPUSD_y']/grouped[' SalesCD_y'])

For other ways of merging tables in python pandas, see this image.
